# LibGDX ParticleEffectPool issue

Tags: java, android, libgdx, particle-system

I have a problem with `ParticleEffectPool` **in libGDX** - the first effect does not show, but why does it work after that?

Here's the code for setting it up:

```
 destroyEffect = new ParticleEffect();
 destroyEffect.load(Gdx.files.internal("destroy.txt"), Gdx.files.internal(""));

 pool = new ParticleEffectPool(destroyEffect, 10, 100);
 activeEffects = new Array<ParticleEffectPool.PooledEffect>();
```

When wanted to show the effect, these call was called:

```
ParticleEffectPool.PooledEffect effect = pool.obtain();

if (effect != null) {
  effect.setPosition(x, y);
  activeEffects.add(effect);
}
```

During render():

```
for (int i = 0; i < activeEffects.size;) {
    ParticleEffectPool.PooledEffect effect = activeEffects.get(i);

    if (effect.isComplete()) {
       pool.free(effect);
       activeEffects.removeIndex(i);
    }
    else {
      effect.draw(batch, deltaTime);
      i++;
    }
}
```

This seems pretty straight forward to me, but the first time it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

effect.isComplete() is true immediately after being added to the pool. So it is freed in the render function and there is no chance to be drawn.

I have found that resetting the effect fixes that in my situation.

Please Add effect.reset(); after obtain statement.

Comment: Amazing! I found no answer in the books or even libGDX forum! This work, thanks!